# Is my proof for uniform continuity correct?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-continuity

I wish to show that $\sqrt{x}$ is uniformly continuous for all $x \geq 0$.

Fix $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \epsilon$. Then $|x - y| < \delta$.

Then $|\sqrt x - \sqrt y| < |\sqrt x - \sqrt y|  |\sqrt x + \sqrt y| = |x - y| < \delta = \epsilon$, so $|\sqrt x - \sqrt y| < \epsilon$.

This seems a little too simple, so I'm not sure if I've done it correctly. Any feedback?

Comment: $|\sqrt x - \sqrt y| < |\sqrt x - \sqrt y|  |\sqrt x + \sqrt y|$ is not true when $x,y$ are relatively small.  Focus on finding  $\delta$ that works when $y=0$ and the rest should fall into place.

Comment: I see, so If I restrict the domain so that $x \geq 1$ then would my proof be correct?

Comment: It would, but then you have proven that $\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous for all $x\ge 1$ and that isn't what you have been asked to prove.

Comment: For the part $x \in [0, 1]$ you may use the fact that $[0, 1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact and $\sqrt x$ is continuous

Comment: Well I guess I can break up the domain into the union of two sets $[0,2] \cup [1, \inf]$, and since $\sqrt x$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ it must be so on $(0,2)$. Using this with the proof above for $x \geq 1$, I take into account the entire domain.

Comment: I was thinking let $\delta = \epsilon^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$|\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}|^2 \leqslant |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}||\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}| = |x-y| \\ \implies |\sqrt{x} - \sqrt{y}| \leqslant  \sqrt{ \ldots}
$$